# getting results from date ranges for query mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query that returns the following,

```
Employee       : AA AA
Manager        : BB BB
Dates          : Jan 26 2022  8:00AM - Feb  2 2022  5:00PM
Days Requested : 6
Type Of Leave  : Annual Leave
Department     : Corporate Accounting & Tax Services
```

what i want to do to get a result for the days ( i am trying to create a pivot table in excel from the data ) that contains all the dates in between for example

```
Employee       : AA AA
Manager        : BB BB
Dates          : Jan 26 2022  8:00AM
Days Requested : 6
Type Of Leave  : Annual Leave
Department     : Corporate Accounting & Tax Services

Employee       : AA AA
Manager        : BB BB
Dates          : Jan 27 2022
Days Requested : 6
Type Of Leave  : Annual Leave
Department     : Corporate Accounting & Tax Services

Employee       : AA AA
Manager        : BB BB
Dates          : Jan 28 2022
Days Requested : 6
Type Of Leave  : Annual Leave
Department     : Corporate Accounting & Tax Services
```

until the end and im stuck.
any help would be appreciated

```
;WITH cte AS(
            SELECT 
            MYUSER.firstname AS Firstname,
            MYUSER.lastname AS Lastname,
            LEAVES.date_start,
            LEAVES.date_end,
            LEAVES.leave_days_requested AS DaysRequested,
            LEAVES.status As Status,
            TYPESLEAVES.types_ofLeaves,
            Manager.user_id AS managerId,
            tbl_department.name_department
            FROM tbl_leaves AS LEAVES
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_user AS MYUSER ON MYUSER.id = LEAVES.tbl_user_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_types_of_leaves AS TYPESLEAVES ON LEAVES.tbl_type_of_leave = TYPESLEAVES.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_manager_user AS ManagerUser ON ManagerUser.tbl_user_id = MYUSER.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_manager AS Manager ON ManagerUser.tbl_manager_id = Manager.id
            INNER JOIN tbl_department ON tbl_department.id = MYUSER.department_id
            WHERE LEAVES.status = 'Pending')
           Select
            CONCAT(a.Firstname,' ',a.Lastname) AS Employee,
            LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(m.firstname, ' ', m.lastname))) AS Manager,
            a.date_start,
            a.date_end,
            a.DaysRequested AS 'Days Requested',
            a.types_ofLeaves AS 'Type Of Leave',
            a.name_department AS 'Department'
            FROM cte a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_user m ON m.id = a.managerId
```

Comment: You need a calendar table. Simple searching will find ways to generate that - dynamically or statically (which is generally better). Once you have that, you simply join your LEAVES table to the calendar using the date_start and date_end columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply i created a date table indeed and joined it together and worked like a charm thxx

```
 INNER JOIN tbl_leaves_dates d
            on d.date >= a.date_start
            and d.date <= a.date_end
```